# Web API: Reading JSON file using StreamContent converting Caffè to Caff (è is missing)

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am reading a big JSON file stored on the server, using WEB API. Following is the code snippet:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
   string filePath = "file path";
   var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

   if (File.Exists(filePath))
   {
      response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
   }

   response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

   return response;
}
```

Everything is working as expected. Apart from a string "Caffè", which is converted to "Caff". (è to space).

Does anyone know what's going on under the hood and the fix?

**Sample of JSON file:**

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "PartnerName":"Caffè Nero"
},

{
   "id": 2,
   "PartnerName":"XYZ"
},
```

JSON response of Get() method is returning right JSON except, Caffè Nero

**Response**:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "PartnerName":"Caff Nero"
},

{
   "id": 2,
   "PartnerName":"XYZ"
},
```

Comment: Feels like an Encoding issue. Try to set StreamReader encoding to UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think it is, any idea how to do that or any links?

Comment: Here I am using StreamContent and I can't find any option to set encoding.

Comment: Worked out the solution, at least it's working for me. Changed the file format from ANSI to UTF-8.